# Is it possible to separate nested populate calls in different methods?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Suppose I have the following schemas:

```
const QuestionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: String,
    question: { type: String, required: true },
    submitter: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

const QuizSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    questions: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }]
});
```

For a particular quiz, I know that if I want to populate the questions, including their submitters, I would do this:

```
quiz.populate({
    path: 'questions',
    model: mongoose.model('Question'),
    options: { 
        sort: { number: 1 }
    },
    populate: {
        path: 'questions.submitter',
        model: mongoose.model('User')
    }
}).exec(cb)
```

Now is it possible to separate the `populate` calls within different methods?

For example, I want to do something like

```
QuizSchema.methods.withQuestions = function () {
    return this.populate({
        path: 'questions',
        model: this.model('Question'),
        options: { 
            sort: { number: 1 }
        }
    });
};

QuizSchema.methods.withSubmitter = function () {
    return this.populate({
        path: 'questions.submitter',
        model: this.model('User')
    });
};
```

in order to do

```
quiz.withQuestions().withSubmitter().execPopulate().then(cb)
```

Unfortunately, when I try doing it this way, `submitter` does not get populated.

Comment: Not in the way you are trying to do it. There is a reason why "nested" calls are indeed "nested"  rather than "chained" in the first place. That is because in the `Query` object chain where `.populate()` actually resides, it does not get called until "after" the actual results have been called by the actual query on the initial model. You can see this clearly by turning on debugging. `mongoose.set('debug', true)`